# Yup parameter validation array value - toLowerCase()

Tags: node.js, parameters, yup

I would like to validate a express controller request with yup. The URL parameter can have 3 different values and I would like to lower case the value of type before validating like.

```
yup.object({

  params: yup.object({
    id: yup.number().min(0).max(3).required(),
    type: yup.mixed().oneOf(['type1', 'type2', 'type3']).required()
  })
});
```

It should pass the check for type1 and Type1.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. This works.

```
params: yup.object({
    id: yup.number().min(0).max(3).required(),
    type: yup.string().lowercase().oneOf(['type1', 'typ2', 'type3']).required()
})
```